# Vb db connection in xampp using LAN

Tags: php, vb.net, phpmyadmin

Good day,

I have a VB application which i need to connect its database in xampp/mysql..

But mysql/xampp is installed to other computer which is networked at my computer.. What will I do?

Answer (score 0):

The MySql server with XAMPP is no different to any other MySql server , with the exception of the interface; it looks a little bit different. If you want to be able to connect to the server, you need to know the server's internal IP address (you can find it with CMD > `ipconfig`). The port will generally be assigned to 3306, so you shouldn't have any issues there.

If you want to grant access to the server from your computer, open up the XAMPP control panel (from the other computer) and click *Shell*. Type in `MySql` and you'll be able to execute commands, from there (which you can use to grant remote access).

Comment: Thank you, may I ask if this code is correct..

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Class connect
    Public Shared myConnection As New MySqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.10; user id=root; database=dbname; password=12589; port=3306;")
End Class

Comment: You have the basics of it correct. If you have problems connecting to the server using those credentials, also ensure that your IP address is granted access to it.